# UpdateInstitutionLogin in AggCat API always returns 200 OK

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I've tried the method UpdateInstitutionLogin in AggCat API with correct userId but wrong password. However, the status is always 200, which means the update doesn't really verify the credentials. Could someone please explain to me this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the refresh flag set to true. It will trigger a refresh request to the FI.
Otherwise the wrong pwd will be saved but when the daily batch will actually hit the FI, then that call will fail.

Ref Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0075_updateinstitutionlogin#Query_Parameters

Comment: I'm sure that I set the refresh flag to true. Could you please double-check this problem?

Comment: Sure.. I'll test and confirm this. r u getting 200 while testing with CC_Bank or some other real FIs ? CC_Bank doesn't verify credential. If it actual FI, then you can also raise a support ticket. https://developer.intuit.com/docs/9_other_resources/0030_support/0010_submit_support_incidents

Comment: I tested both with CC Bank and CIBC. Both of them experienced the same problem. I've raised a support ticket with case # 00004303